# REST: Relations between individual resources

Tags: rest, standards, relation, hateoas

Can someone tell me how to "RESTfully" create a relation between two individual resources?
I have figured out several approaches, but I would like to stick to standards.
I'll list several examples to show you guys what I already came up with.
Examples will have a post resource which has to be linked to a category resource.

**Note:** all examples presume that both resources already exist.

Ex 1:

```
PATCH /post/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: api-host
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "post": {
        "links": {
            "category": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Ex 2:

```
POST /post/1/category/2 HTTP/1.1
Host: api-host
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{}
```

Ex 3:

```
POST /relations?post=id&category=id
Host: api-host
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{}
```

And what would be the best way to remove the relationship between these 2 resources?

**"Solution"**:
As LINK and UNLINK aren't supported anymore, the best solution imo (hat tip @Bramus) would be the PATCH example.

So to create a link you would call:

```
PATCH /post/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: api-host
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "post": {
        "links": {
            "category": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

And to remove it:

```
PATCH /post/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: api-host
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "post": {
        "links": {
            "category": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why replace HTTP verbs? If you're looking for a standard the HTTP verbs are the top you can use,Imo

Comment: @Andrea_86 because they **used to** exist, they aren't used/supported anymore. That's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place a `Post` into a `Category` I'd use a simple `PATCH` passing in all those `categories` as an array (if multiple categories may be selected), or a single `category` key-value pair.

- Multiple Categories:

  ```
  PATCH /post/1 HTTP/1.1
  Host: api-host
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json
  Cache-Control: no-cache

  {
      "categories": [2, 3]
  }
  ```
- Single Category:

  ```
  PATCH /post/1 HTTP/1.1
  Host: api-host
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json
  Cache-Control: no-cache

  {
      "category": 2
  }
  ```

It resembles your first example, yet it differs a little as it passes in the categories as an array / single value. I prefer this method as it mimics what one would do via a normal HTML form: multiple checkboxes for multiple categories (result is an array that gets posted) or a dropdown (result is a single value that gets posted).

On a sidenote I don't see a category as a link, but as a sub-entity/sub-resource:

- Sub-entities indicate a relationship between two *(mostly different type of)* entities.
- Links are mostly used for navigation (`next`, `prev`, `parent`, `me`, ...)

The use of the links key inside your PATCH is not compatible with this ideology.

Comment: how would you handle unlinks of a category?

Comment: Same call: All existing selected categories would be removed and replaced by the new ones sent in.

Comment: Hmm, going to modify my example to fit this answer, seems legit.

Comment: The body (request entity) of PATCH is supposed to describe patch operations, not just some part of the resource.  Something like http://jsonpatch.com/ .  Many people are using PATCH in the way you suggest...but that's not it's intent see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ChrisDaMour. Wasn't aware of the fact that `PATCH` should contain deltas. When going “down the rabbit hole” on this subject I stumbled upon [RFC6902](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902), which could form a good starting point when rolling your own implementation _(Sidenote: couldn't immediately find what HAL/Siren/etc. need)_

Answer (score 0):

You've already accepted an answer that correlates with your attempts to use PATCH, but i'd like to propose an alternate solution.  I'd start with something very simple.  Add a new link to your Post resource type for every category that it can be put into.

In HAL it would look something like this:

```
x:category-add : [
    { "href" : "url/to/add/post/x/to/category/1", title : "Add Category 1"},
    { "href" : "url/to/add/post/x/to/category/2", title : "Add Category 2"},
    { "href" : "url/to/add/post/x/to/category/3", title : "Add Category 3"},
    { "href" : "url/to/add/post/x/to/category/4", title : "Add Category 4"},
]
```

That would be dead simple.  The client has to know so much less information to execute your use case of adding a post to a category.  They never have to store URLs and know where to put them in some template.

Alternatively, you could use the name field to indicate if a post is already a member or not.  Something like:

```
x:category : [
    { "href" : "url/to/add/post/x/to/category/1", name : "add", title : "Add Category 1"},
    { "href" : "url/to/remove/post/x/to/category/2", name : "remove", title : "Remove Category 2"},
    { "href" : "url/to/add/post/x/to/category/3", name : "add", title : "Add Category 3"},
    { "href" : "url/to/remove/post/x/to/category/4", name : "remove", title : "Remove Category 4"},
]
```

From here you might find that you have so many categories that having a link for each one could be cumbersome.  The answer to that is an intermediate resource linked from your post resource.  Call it post-category-management. Link to it from your Post via a relationship like x:post-category-management.  Have this resource allow paging through categories, fuzzy searching for categories, some way to remove all categories, offer suggested categories.

```
{
  x:category-suggested : [
    { href : "path/to/add/suggeted/category/Z", title : "Category Z"}
  ],
  x:category-available : [
    { "href" : "url/to/add/post/x/to/category/1", title : "Add Category 1"},
  ],
  next : { href : "url/to/next/available/categories" },
  x:category-search : { href : "url/to/search/for/categories/for/post/x{?term}", templated : true}
}
```

This seems a lot simpler to me.  What helped me get her was imaging a Web Application using RESTful Architecture and what types of links I would want it to have if i didn't have javascript and form controls.  As the imaginary app got more complicated it was clear each post needs a category management page.  A html page ISA resource.

Once i got that going, I'd start supporting some fancier stuff.  Like DELETE verbs sent to applied categories URLs to remove them from the post.  To me even though posts are in categories, i can also think of categories being in a post.  In an entity relationship diagram it'd be the link that you actually want to remove, and the DELETE would be sent with the URL of that link, not the actual category.

Maybe then I'd support true PATCH requests (where the request entity is a patch request like jsonpatch) to allow very advanced client behaviours.